# How to send email without stock mail app?

Tags: ios, swift

How can I send mail on button action without using the stock iOS mail app?

```
var toAdress = "something@someting.com"
var fromAdress = "from@email.com"
var subject = "Something subject"
var message = "message text"
```

And i want to send using this info on buttonAction. Any API that does NOT use the stock IOS mail app?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow however, a search for "iOS SMTP framework" will give you some options, such as MailCore

Answer (score 1):

If by “without using the stock iOS mail app” you mean send e-mail without switching to the Mail app, you can use [MFMailComposeViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMailComposeViewController_class/index.html) to present an e-mail dialog within your app, and you can set the to, subject, and message fields for the user to edit (the “from” is the user's address).

If you mean without using this, then unless you are implementing an actual alternative e-mail client it seems very doubtful that you'd want to get into it. Sending e-mail is going to require user interaction and setup for the SMTP server, unless *you* control the mail server. And if you do control the mail server, you could quite simply set up a web API and make a http call to send the e-mail through your server (this would be suitable, e.g., if the intent is to let the user send *you* e-mail, or trigger an e-mail sent from *you* to the user).